# how to enter data into an array with a loop. laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert data from the database into an array that can be increased in number. So maybe you can use a loop but the data is stacked, not added and returns the last data

i am trying to use for with $i++ to generate $variable.$i. that's what I was expecting but I don't understand how to run it

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $sumjnssuara; $i++){
            $koleksi = [];
            ${"suwara{$i}"} = DB::table('suara')->where('suara','Suara '.$i)->pluck('jml_suara')->sum();
            array_push($koleksi, ${"suwara{$i}"});
        }
```

the problem might be solved if $suwara1++ and makes the $koleksi array grow

Comment: your syntax should like this : $s = "suwara{$i}"; $$s = <your db statement> ; array_push($koleski, $$s);  but just do : $s = <your db statement>; array_push($koleski, $s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you recreate the array at each iteration. you need to create it outside the loop:

```
$koleksi = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < $sumjnssuara; $i++){
    ${"suwara{$i}"} = DB::table('suara')->where('suara','Suara '.$i)->pluck('jml_suara')->sum();
    array_push($koleksi, ${"suwara{$i}"});
}
```

Then I would get rid of creating variables with a different name in each iteration. That doesn't make sense:

```
$koleksi = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < $sumjnssuara; $i++){
    $suwara = DB::table('suara')->where('suara','Suara '.$i)->pluck('jml_suara')->sum();
    $koleksi[] = $suwara;
}
```

And finally all of this can be implemented with a single query in the database:

```
$koleksi = DB::table('suara')
    ->groupBy('suara')
    ->pluck(DB::raw('sum(jml_suara) as sum'), 'suara')
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: it is very efficient, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must move this line

```php
$koleksi = [];
```

outside of your loop, otherwise on each iteration you reset it back to empty (`[]`) so at the end of the loop it will be holding only last element.

```php
$koleksi = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < $sumjnssuara; $i++){
    ${"suwara{$i}"} = DB::table('suara')->where('suara','Suara '.$i)->pluck('jml_suara')->sum();
    array_push($koleksi, ${"suwara{$i}"});
}
```

I also wonder what the point of so complex variable name creation. `array_push()` will push the value anyway so there's no point. Even more, there's no point for `array_push()` either:

```php
$koleksi = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < $sumjnssuara; $i++){
    $koleksi[] = DB::table('suara')->where('suara','Suara '.$i)->pluck('jml_suara')->sum();
}
```

Finally, I'd replace `'Suara '.$i` of your `where()` with `"Suara {$i}"` simply for better readability.

Comment: and thanks for the explanation.
I'm very helped